# Непонятное поведение виджетов

Tags: python, pyqt5

Есть самописный виджет унаследованный от QtWidgets.QWidget, который в свою очередь используется для наполнения QListWidget.
Примерный код:

```
class QCustomQWidget (QtWidgets.QWidget):
#Класс для создания итемов в списке.
def __init__ (self, parent = None):
    super(QCustomQWidget, self).__init__(parent)
    self.textQHBoxLayout = QtWidgets.QHBoxLayout()
    self.host = QtWidgets.QLabel()
    self.port = QtWidgets.QLabel()
    self.textQHBoxLayout.addWidget(self.host)
    self.textQHBoxLayout.addWidget(self.port)
    self.allQHBoxLayout = QtWidgets.QHBoxLayout()
    self.allQHBoxLayout.addLayout(self.textQHBoxLayout, 1)
    self.setLayout(self.allQHBoxLayout)

def setHost(self, text):
    self.host.setText(text)

def setPort(self, text):
    self.port.setText(text)
```

И метод для заполнения QListWidget экземплярами этого класса (Сам метод уже в другом классе):

```
def PortsListFill(self, ports):
    for port in ports:
        item = QCustomQWidget()
        item.setPort(port['port'])
        item.setHost(port['name'])
        myQlistWidgetItem = QtWidgets.QListWidgetItem(self.PortList)
        myQlistWidgetItem.setSizeHint(item.sizeHint())
        self.PortList.addItem(myQlistWidgetItem)
        self.PortList.setItemWidget(myQlistWidgetItem, item)
```

Проблема заключается в том, что при вызове метода заполняющего метода из функции build при отрисовки главного окна. Метод отрабатывает правильно, а когда этот же метод вызывается из другого метода. QCustomWidget отрисовывается отдельным окном, а не как QListWidget. Помогите пожалуйста понять в чём проблема и исправить.

Comment: 1) Не называйте, пожалуйста, свои виджеты с префиксом `Q`, это путает -- так только классы `Qt` рекомендуется называть. 2) Код с `self.QListWidget.` очень странный, точно нигде не ошиблись? Это вы так поле именем класса назвали? 3) `self.item = ` и  `self.myQlistWidgetItem = ` выглядят подозрительно. Потому что они в цикле и тот метод может быть вызыван повторно, поэтому вопрос зачем их запоминать в поле текущего класса и что произойдет с виджетами что были до этого в тех переменных? 4) Как вы используете метод listWdigetFill?

Comment: Код примерный, частично измененный, важна суть проблемы которая заключается в том, что при вызове метода listWidgetFill из разных методов одного класса - я получаю разный результат.

Comment: C `self.item` где-то еще работаете или только в методе `listWdigetFill`?

Comment: Нет, но обращаюсь к элементам QListWidgetItem, в других методах

Comment: Мб в этом как раз и проблема. По описанию [setItemWidget](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qlistwidget.html#setItemWidget) виджет должен быть статичным, иначе метод setItemWidget не подходит и нужно через делегаты делать

Comment: Нет, история та же. но self. действительно не нужен.

Comment: Сложно что-то сказать... Можете минимальный пример с проблемой в вопрос добавить? Чтобы я (или другой желающий) мог запустить его и увидеть вашу проблему?

Comment: Изменил проблемные вставки кода, хотя вряд-ли это сильно что-то изменит. Весь код выкладывать нет смысла, ибо много данных подтягивается извне. Есть новые подробности. По всей видимости проблема проявляется когда перед этим вызываешь метод self.PortList.clear(). Если Port List не чистить - проблема не проявляется.

Comment: Те данные, что подтягиваются извне можно заменить статичными данными, заполняемые в коде\

Comment: В метод надо передавать словарь в котором есть поля 'port', 'name'